# Why was my treasure map removed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Last night I was playing Skyrim, and after I went into Breezehome a message said "Treasure Map III Removed". Sure enough, it was gone. I reloaded, and tried again. Same result.

I can go into any other location, but if I go into my house the same thing always happens.

I figure this is a bug, but is there a trigger?

Comment: Did you already get the treasure described by that map?

Comment: If I did it was by accident, I never went looking for it. If I did, why would it only go away when I go into that specific building?

Comment: Beats me. I was just trying to narrow down what might be going on. I know the treasure chest only spawns once you have the map, so maybe something can cause them to despawn, which maybe causes the map to disappear?

Comment: Same thing happened to me for Treasure Map X when I entered the Temple of Kynareth in White Run. No clue how or why it happened and 99% sure I never located this treasure chest. Every other house/building works just fine, except this one.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple result for this is to just look up an image of the map. This glitch in particular can not be fixed without an item code and respawning the map itself. If you can just look up an image of the map then you can simply just go get the treasure and forget about it problem solved. Hope this helps you and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it was removed, there was a couple of simple explanations:

- You already got the treasure.
- You dropped the treasure map but didn't realize or forgot you did it.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the loaded cell in question that removes your map triggers a bug where the game thinks you have already found the treasure or treats the map as if it should not be there or needs to be removed (Rather like the weird thing that happens when you quit a job for the Thieves Guild and it still removes a gem from you inventory even if it is yours and not given or stolen from the target) a way to fix this is to refrain from entering cells that remove the map until you have found the treasure, (Unless you really don't want the treasure) This should prevent the game from removing the map when the cell is loaded.